# 503 Error After Microsoft Request Routing Is Installed - 32 bit 64 bit madness

Tags: windows-server-2008, routing, asp.net, iis-7.5

I have a requirement to install the Microsoft Request Routing component for IIS 7.5 running on a Windows 2008 R2 SP1 64Bit machine.

After installing Microsoft Request Routing via the Web Platform installer our ASP.NET 4.0 application gets a "HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable."

The Windows event log error details says:

```
The Module DLL 'C:\Program Files\IIS\Application Request Routing\requestRouter.dll' could not be loaded due to a configuration problem. The current configuration only supports loading images built for a AMD64 processor architecture. The data field contains the error number. To learn more about this issue, including how to troubleshooting this kind of processor architecture mismatch error, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=29349.
```

I can make this error go away by changing the application pool to run in 32 bit mode by changing the "Enable 32-Bit Applications" setting to true.

However I would prefer not to have to do that to resolve the issue.

My questions are:

1. Why is the Microsoft Request Routing feature trying to load a 32 bit version, isn't there a 64 bit version for it?
2. How do I resolve this issue without having to change my application pool to a 32 bit mode?

Comment: Have you tried the actual physical download link provided by Microsoft at IIS.NET for ARR x64 instead of the WebPI link? Sounds like it might be broken.

Comment: I'll look into that

Comment: Sadly, I still get the same error after following the instructions on this page: http://blogs.iis.net/wonyoo/archive/2011/04/20/how-to-install-application-request-routing-arr-2-5-without-web-platform-installer-webpi.aspx